# Unable to insert new record into "site.com's" form

Tags: site.com

I have created a web page , added a form with the objects field. i am trying to insert data after clicking the "preview page "button but getting this following error. please help.

"**We're unable to retrieve your data due to an error.**"

Comment: Did you check to see if the fields are read only?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Bharadwaj. Your question is very vague and we need specifics to help out. Please see our FAQ on asking questions - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's also important to know which specific object you're trying to access along with whether you're talking about a secure portal accessed through SF "sites" and which license type you have (assuming this isn't a Dev Org. Not all objects are directly accessible through portals (or sites) unless you have the proper license for portal users.

Comment: Hi Bill,the fields are not checked for read only.I have also provided the read and create permission.

Comment: Hi Mike,Sorry for asking a vague question.

Comment: what i meant by asking is, i want to make a web page through site.com studio and create new record in custom objects by entering data through that page. So after creating the page and assigning object to it i am previewing the page and entering data but getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

I came across similar situation and ended up with that it is a WAD. This error will be shown when we do not enter data in correct format. eg if in email we enter "abc" instead if we enter "abc@hjds.com" then we don't get error. Client side validation is the only workaround here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a user "profile" set up for sites users that includes access to your custom object? If not, you won't be able to access those objects from sites and will get an error message of the kind you're seeing.

Are these custom "objects" perhaps instead custom "fields" on say Opportunity or Accounts? If so, that could be the problem. If you're trying to access any fields (standard or custom) on Accounts, Opportunities, Events or Leads (and a few others), unless you have full partner licenses, you'll need to mirror them through a Custom Object that contains those fields and then sync them back to the primary object using triggers or batchable classes.

Comment: yes...the permission(Site.com Contributor User and Site.com Publisher User) for being site user and the custom object access(read and create) are also provided.

Comment: Those permissions are on the Sites User Profile? Is there a custom controller? If so, is it set for "Global"? If not, it most likely won't be able to access the objects.

Comment: yes..these are site user profile permissions. Also there are no apex classes associated with the page so there are no custom controllers. is there any other way..?

Comment: Does what I added to my post above apply to your situation? Regardless, could you update your original question by editing it to add more specific details on object names and fields, along with some page code please? I don't think anyone can help you further without it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your field level security and also if you are setting form field values with jquery or javascript than don't make them hidden.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do check the Data Type against the input field.
If your data type is number and your submitting a text then 
"We're unable to retrieve your data due to an error." messages is shown.

The value should match against the data type of an object and validation 
for the same can be done on client side.
May be this should help

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different possibilities that I can think of:

1. It could be that the Site's Guest User does not have the correct permissions on the Object (CRUD) or Object's fields (Field Level Security).  Note that this is NOT the Site Contributor or Site Publisher user that you use to construct the Site.  You can see the permissions by navigating to the Site Configuration page and clicking on the Guest User Profile.  Clicking on the Guest User Profile will take you to a normal profile edit screen where you can check CRUD and FLS.  Obviously you need Create and Read to use a form.
   [image: Site.com Guest User Profile]
2. The data connection needs to be repaired.  See [this page in the docs](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_repair.htm&language=en_US).  It can happen if:
   2.1 Field has been renamed since the form was created.
   2.2 Field has been deleted since the form was created.
   2.3 Field has been made not visible since the form was created. 
   2.4 A new required field has been added to the object since the form was created. 
   2.5 Permissions have changed since the form was created.
3. Something else.  You set up a debug log for the Site User.  In the Lookup dialog type the name (or beginning of the name) of the Site Guest User.  It should be in the form or Site Name Site Guest User, e.g., for a site named Test Site, it would be Test Site Site Guest User.  You can also get the user's name from the profile page, by clicking the View Users button.  Here's an example of the debug log Lookup:
   [image: Site Guest User Debug Log]